# Spring Integration TcpInboundGateway Read exception resulting in SocketException:Connection reset

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring boot as per examples for TcpInboundGateway,so different devices send data to this Gateways,things works fine but in between in logs it showing following exception:

```
2015-12-29 18:42:19.455 ERROR 3465 --- [ool-3-thread-47] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Read exception 106.221.159.216:38170:8765:934c050d-c4b5-4466-98ab-ee87714c3d00 SocketException:Connection reset
```

If this exception is resetting connection then how to avoid this reset?What is the cause of this error?

My code as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class SpringIntegrationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationApplication.class, args);       
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringIntegrationApplication.class);
    }

    private static Class<SpringIntegrationApplication> applicationClass = SpringIntegrationApplication.class;


    @Bean
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf(){
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(8765);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    TcpInboundGateway tcpGate(){

        TcpInboundGateway gateway=new TcpInboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(cf());
        gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel(){

        return new DirectChannel();
    }


    @MessageEndpoint 
    public class Echo {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requestChannel")
    public byte[] echo(byte[] in,@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Header("ip_address") String ip){

        byte[] rawbytes = gosDataSerivce.byteArrayToHex(in,ip);//Process bytes and returns result

        return rawbytes;    

    }
    }

}
```

After setting `singleUse` to `true` now exception message is changed slightly.

```
2015-12-31 06:09:00.481 ERROR 16450 --- [ool-3-thread-10] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Read exception 106.221.146.40:9195:8765:1b4755e8-5b0c-44b9-b4e6-b3aacc25e228 SocketException:Connection reset
```

**Use Case:**
I have several clients that established GPRS connection to `TcpInboundGateWay` and sends login packet,our server will reply to this login packet.If client receives server reply to login packet then it will send data packets at regular interval. Server needs to reply to these packet also if server fails to send reply to those data packets then client GPRS connection is terminated and client will try to establish connections again.Let me know if this use case can be handle with `TcpInboundGateWay`

**Network Trace Analysis**
General flow of communication between client and server is as follows:Client sends login packet from `ip` say `106.221.148.165` so at server connection named `106.221.148.165:63430:8765:cc105da2-dae4-494b-af9c-d1ba268f34f1` is created, that client sends subsequent packets from that `ip` only.So everything works fine,but after some time same client sends its login packet from another `ip` say `106.221.142.204`.And subsequent packets from new `ip`.But in logs following error comes that for previous connection exception occurred.

```
2016-01-05 05:16:14.871 ERROR 6819 --- [pool-3-thread-5] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Read exception 106.221.148.165:63430:8765:cc105da2-dae4-494b-af9c-d1ba268f34f1 SocketException:Connection reset
```

I have set `singleUse` `true` and I am using `spring integration 4.2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is emitted when the client closes the socket - if your client only sends one message then closes the socket, you can set `singleUse` to `true` and it will suppress this message (as long as the socket is closed normally - between messages).

With Spring Integration version 4.2 and later, the message is not emitted on a normal close, even if `singleUse` is `false`.

Comment: I am using Spring Integration 4.2.1,and after setting singleUse to true the exception message is changed slightly.Adding it in question and also my usecase

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two error messages above. Your use case is fine. If you are seeing this exception with 4.2.x (regardless of single-use), a reset means the client is closing (aborting) the socket. You might need to look at a network trace and/or the client code to see why. [Here's a description of orderly Vs. aborted socket closure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/articles/connection_release.html). The default serializer will append CRLF to the message, perhaps the client doesn't like that? (The default deserializer expects CRLF at the end too).

Comment: You probably need to look at the client code; a RST is usually only sent if the client closes the socket with unread data in its buffer. It will send a FIN on the close if all the data is read. RST is an aborted close.

Comment: as of now we don't have access to client code..client is third party service provider.

Comment: You need to ask them why the client is resetting the connection then (or ignore the log message).

Comment: if we set singleUse to true then does that mean connection is valid for single message only.

Comment: Right, so set it to `false` then, to support multiple packets. Another possibility for the RST might be the network (some router) is resetting the connection if it's idle? Do you detect a pattern - e.g. the RST appears 60 seconds after the last real packet.